# How to log into an Azure Managed Grafana with personal account

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-managed-grafana

I would like to try out Azure Managed Grafana, but I cannot log in with the Microsoft account that owns the resource (and the subscription).

I get the error `"You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead."`.

This is a personal subscription, and this account has the `Grafana Admin` role.

What am I missing?

[image: Microsoft login prompt showing the text "You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead."]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-grafana/how-to-share-grafana-workspace#supported-grafana-roles):

> Azure Managed Grafana doesn't support personal Microsoft accounts (a.k.a., MSA) currently.

You can refer to [Grafana role assignment using Azure AD OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952293/grafana-role-assignment-using-azure-ad-oauth), [Role mapping issue with AzureAD](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/23358), and [Manage users globally](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/manage-users-and-permissions/manage-server-users/)

Comment: Ah, thank you! Didn't spot it in the docs. Should be a bit more prominent, maybe in the Overview... I'll send a PR to add the disclaimer there.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/pull/94285