# Controlling Grafana dashboard permissions

Tags: oauth-2.0, grafana

While reviewing the [Grafana OAuth2 Authentication](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/generic-oauth/#before-you-begin) setup page and looking at [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60004918/6280556), I was trying to see if there is a way to control the permissions for the Grafana `dashboards` separately?

For example, the user roles have been defined in the `grafana.ini` such that all users within `.admin_group` will have `Admin` access, within `.editor_group` have `Editor` access and rest would be `Viewers`.

```
role_attribute_path = contains(groups[*], '{{ .admin_group }}') && 'Admin' || \
contains(groups[*], '{{ .editor_group }}') && 'Editor' || \
'Viewer'
```

In addition, is there a way (apart from setting it in `permissions` tab in the dashboard) to make sure that the person who creates a dashboard has `editor` access to their dashboards and not the others, while keeping their initial access the same?
It seems that with the above role setting the user ends up getting `editor` access to all dashboards in Grafana.

Comment: Editor is an [organization role](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/roles-and-permissions/#organization-roles), and thus it allows to edit every dashboard (and not only). If you want to allow edit only some dashboards, user should have Viewer role with separate per dashboard permissions. Not sure you can allow them to create dashboards in this setup though.

Comment: thanks for getting back @markalex!

Can the [editors_can_admin](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/user-management/server-user-management/grant-editor-admin-permissions/#grant-editors-administrator-permissions) flag be used for this and if so will it give editor permission to create/update their own dashboards or others as well?

Comment: I don't see how it can be useful for you, since you don't want to grant editor role to users.

Comment: That's true,  Is [defining permissions per dashboard in a separate yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76038623/6280556) something you've looked into?  Is it applied at the dashboard folder level? 
Further reference [RBAC](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/roles-and-permissions/access-control/rbac-grafana-provisioning/)